# Identify duplicate time-series sequences in Postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a time series table (in a Postgres DB) with columns

```
item_id,  country_id,  year,  month, value
```

Within this table there are duplicate time series: they have the same country_id and time series dates/values, but have been assigned a different item_id, for example: 'Red Apples' and 'Apples, Red'

How can I identify these duplicate time series? I want (country_id, year, month, value) to match across all the dates that exist for the item.

I am a beginner, so please forgive any details I've left out. I'm mainly looking for the conceptual approach - I could implement it in Postgres or python/Pandas.

So for example, I'd like to be able to detect something like this:

```
item_id,     country_id,     year,     month,    value
-------------------------------------------------------
Red Apples   5               1996      1         300
Red Apples   5               1996      2         500
Red Apples   5               1996      3         370
Apples, Red  5               1996      1         300
Apples, Red  5               1996      2         500
Apples, Red  5               1996      3         370
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
item_id1,     item_id2,      country_id,     year,     month_range
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Red Apples    Apples, Red         5          1996       [1,3]
```

Something like this would also be ok:

```
item_id1,     item_id2,      country_id,     year,     time_month,   value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Red Apples    Apples, Red         5          1996         1           300
Red Apples    Apples, Red         5          1996         2           500
Red Apples    Apples, Red         5          1996         3           370
```

I thought of trying something like this:

```
select distinct A.country_id, A.item_id, B.item_id, A.year, A.month, A.value
                      from my_table as A,
                      my_table as B 
                      where
                      (A.country_id=B.country_id and 
                      A.item_id<>B.item_id and 
                      A.year=B.year and 
                      A.month=B.month and 
                      A.value=B.value )
```

And then I'd check to make sure all date/values appear for each item_id pair identified.
But I'd like to check all dates/values at once if possible.

I'm not sure if a table join would be appropriate...?

Comment: What if your data has another entry, like `Yellow Bananas,5,1996,1,300` -- is it also counted as a duplicate here?

Comment: I only want to identify duplicate time-series or at least sub-series. Not coincidental matches of only one date.

Comment: What is the minimal length of the series? And how to deal with series that cross year boundary, like `1996-12,1997-1`?

Comment: Each (item_id, country_id) pair will have several years of data, and I'd want to find at least 3 consecutive months that are identical.The specific format of the output is not important, as long as it returns all the item_ids and country_ids & dates where the values are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Please, see **update below**!</sub>

Unless you provide more details on the sample data and expected result, I think the following query might help:

```sql
SELECT country_id,  year,  month, value
  FROM a_table
 GROUP BY country_id,  year,  month, value
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

This query will show you all the entries, that are equal except for the `item_id`.
If you'd like to find all rows that corresponds to the duplicated groups, use this query:

```sql
SELECT item_id, country_id,  year,  month, value
  FROM a_table
 WHERE (country_id,  year,  month, value)
    IN (
    SELECT country_id,  year,  month, value
      FROM a_table
     GROUP BY country_id,  year,  month, value
    HAVING count(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY country_id,  year,  month, value, item_id;
```

I've made column `item_id` being last one in the sorting order, it should make it more visible to identify duplicates. Feel free to adjust. This query might take a while, depends on your data.

In order to avoid such cases in the future (duplicated date) you might want to create a Unique constraint, like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE a_table ADD CONSTRAIN u_cymv
    UNIQUE (country_id,  year,  month, value);
```

---

**EDIT:**
After comments were added I've come up with the following query to find series of duplicates:

```
WITH a_table(item_id,country_id,year,month,value) AS (VALUES
    ('Red Apples'::text,5,1996,1,300::numeric),
    ('Red Apples',5,1996,2,500),
    ('Red Apples',5,1996,3,370),
    ('Apples, Red',5,1996,1,300),
    ('Apples, Red',5,1996,2,500),
    ('Apples, Red',5,1996,3,370)
), dups AS (
    SELECT string_agg(item_id,'/') AS items,
           country_id,value,
           daterange(to_date(year::text||month,'YYYYMM'),
                     (to_date(year::text||month,'YYYYMM')
                      +INTERVAL'1mon')::date,'[)') AS range
      FROM a_table
     GROUP BY country_id,year,month,value
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
SELECT grp,count(*),items,country_id,
       daterange(min(lower(range)), max(upper(range)), '[)') r,
       array_agg(value)
  FROM ( 
    SELECT items,country_id,range,value,
           sum(g) OVER (ORDER BY country_id, range) grp
      FROM (
        SELECT items,country_id,
               range,value,
               CASE WHEN lag(range) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id
                                          ORDER BY range) -|- range
                    THEN NULL ELSE 1 END g
          FROM dups) s
    ) s
 GROUP BY grp,country_id,items
HAVING count(*) >= 3
 ORDER BY country_id,r,items;
```

What it does:

1. `a_table` is a copy of the provided sample data;
2. `dups` is the one finding duplicated records. I'm also converting `year,month` columns into a `daterange`, as I see no other way to properly find series that are crossing NY;
3. after duplicates are outlined, I am comparing previous `range` (within a `country_id`) with the current one if they are not [adjacent](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html), group flag `g` is set;
4. next, I use a [running total effect](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) of the `sum()` function to create group identifier `grp`. For the sample data this produces just one group though;
5. finally, I use `grp` for the `GROUP BY` to group data into series. I also include `country_id` and `items` into the `GROUP BY`, but this is just to avoid wrapping them into aggregate funcitons — they will be unique per `grp` anyway. I also forming a new `daterange` column, this is due to `range` types do not have built in aggregate functions.

You might need to increase `work_mem` prior to executing this query, up to `1GB` I'd said (depending on the number of rows in your real table).
Please, try this out and let me know if it works for you. It'd be nice if you could share `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` for this one.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is clearer now. I'm not trying to identify duplicated rows, but entire data series that have been given 2 different names.

Comment: (Your suggestion maybe works, but I really want to see the 2 conflicting item_id values)

Comment: Thanks, this gets me part of the way there. It still doesn't identify the conflicting item_ids, though, and my original table has 10 million rows, and maybe one thousand different item_ids, so it can't really be done manually.

Comment: @user3591836, I don't understand what you mean by *identify*? The query I provided returns *only* duplicated series. Please, precise.

Comment: I'd like the output to include the item_id of all the duplicate time series, plus the time interval on which they are the same.

Something like this
'Red Apples', 'Apples, Red', 1996, [1,3]

Comment: @user3591836, please, update your question with expected output for the sample data you've used.

Comment: This is AMAZING!! Thank you. I'll share the EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) when I have time to run it properly. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY country_id, year, month, value
HAVING count(item_id) > 1

!This is untested!